# SSBO hash table, missing values

Tags: c++, opengl, hash, graphics, glsl

I am trying to run a little data compression experiment. I am trying to compress 3D textures into hash tables to avoid storing empty volume information.

To this effect I wrote the hashing function and retreiving function (they are in different shaders):

```
struct Voxel
{
    int filled;
    ivec4 position;
    vec4 normal;
    vec4 color;
};

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer voxel_buffer
{
    uint index;
    Voxel voxels[];
};
// Data storing shader
int a_size = 10000000;
void insert(vec3 pos, Voxel value) {
    ivec3 discretized = ivec3(pos / v_size);
    int index = int(pow(7, discretized.x) * pow(2, discretized.y) * pow(3, discretized.z)) % a_size;

    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        if(atomicCompSwap(voxels[index].filled, 0, 1) == 0) {
           Voxel c_voxel = voxels[index];
           value.position = ivec4(discretized, 1);
           voxels[index] = value;
           break;
         }

        index = (index * index) % a_size;
    }
}
//Data reading shader
int a_size = 10000000;
vec4 fetch(vec3 pos) {
    ivec3 discretized = ivec3(pos / v_size);
    int index = int(pow(7, discretized.x) * pow(2, discretized.y) * pow(3, discretized.z)) % a_size;

    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        Voxel c_voxel = voxels[index];

        if(ivec4(discretized,1) == voxels[index].position)
            return voxels[index].color;

        index = (index * index) % a_size;
    }
}
```

My current issue however is that I am missing about 90% of the voxel values:

[image]

The intended result is:

[image]

I have had some ideas as to what could be wrong but none seem to be it:

- Number of hashes is bigger than array size. I allocated 100 000 000 bytes, the total size of the voxel structure should be 4*4*3 = 48, giving me a total possible element number of 2 083 333.33. I capped the array size at a million, which is half of that, so I shouldn't be accessing unallocated memory.
- Hash function collides more than 50 times, causing most of the elements to be discarded. I could be wrong, but I am using quadratic updating to increase the hashed index, this should be better than linear. And I am also relying on the FTA to guarantee unique key generation before digesting. So I am skeptic that so many hashes collide more than 50 times. Moreover, the fact that the voxels that were kept are all in such a nice region (a liner diagonal slice)
  doesn't seem to match this hypothesis. If it was a collision problem I should be seeing a semi uniform distribution of wholes, not such a nicely defined region.
- Driver can't allocate that much vram for the ssbo. I am using a GTX 1070 with the latest NVIDIA drivers, the documentation says that the spec guarantees a minimum size of 128 MB but that most implementations let you allocate up to the total memory size. I allocated 100 000 000 bytes, which is under the upper limit, and even if the driver aligns my memory to 128 MB it should not affect the result of my computations since i keep track of the logical array size myself.

Any ideas as to why I am loosing so much information when compressing?

EDIT:
Added atomic operations based on a comment

EDIT 2:
Solution was found in a comment, result:
[image]

Some memory loss still happens, but that was expected.

Comment: Ypu have totally incoherent, unsynchronized non-atmoic  reads and writes to that buffer, how do you expect this to work at all?

Comment: Reads are synchronized, they are in a different shader that is called after the wrting one and blocked through the SBBO memory bit. In Nvidia drivers (the ones I am currently using), unsynchronized writing isn't an issue in the sense that I only care about something being in the buffer at the right index.

I know this works because it was tested with linear buffering and it worked with no issue. In other words, it's the fact that I am hashing the function that is causing a problem, not the lack of synchronization. Memory corruption or loss are acceptable.

Comment: I'm talking about the reads where you check for collision in the "storing" shader. This collision handling is bound to fail. You need atomics for that to work.

Comment: It is a fair criticism, in my experience for this kind of thing the atomic operations don't make that much of a difference (you do get better results with them, but not that much to explain the full issue).

I nonetheless added them as suggested and ran the program again. Output is identical.

Comment: I honestly think the problem may be with the way I am hashing things.

Comment: OK, another idea: `pow(7, discretized.x) * pow(2, discretized.y) * pow(3, discretized.z)` might even overlfow the float range. You might end up with infinity. And after a conversion to `int`, you might be at `0`. with index 0, your quadratic probing stays at 0 forever and no data will be added.

Comment: And if using pure int math, `pow(2,x)` will be drawing the whole equation to 0 for any `x >= 32`

Comment: That could actually be the issue, do you have any suggestion for a better hash function? I thought going over the limit would simply "wrap around" rather than capping at 0 so that it would work modulus the highest possible value

Comment: You sir are a brilliant mathematician and programmer

Comment: "I thought going over the limit would simply "wrap around" rather than capping at 0" Well, a power of two modulo a smaller power of two (2^32 or 2^31 for `uint`/`int`) is always 0, so wrap-around won't help you here.

Comment: However, I have not looked into the spec, but I'm not sure if relying on some integer overflow would be unedefined behavior or not. You should really look that up to not get some bad surprises on some implementations...

Comment: I completely changed the hash function to something that was less mathematically beautiful and more friendly to the hardware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hash function

> ```
> int(pow(7, discretized.x) * pow(2, discretized.y) * pow(3, discretized.z)) % a_size;
> ```

is very poor. Since `discretized` is an `ivec3`, the whole operation is working on integers, and the term `pow(2, discretized.y)` will be `0` for whenever `discretized.y` is `>= 31`, resulting in your complete hash value to evaluate to `0`. Also, for `discretized.y < 0`, you should get 0, as the resulting fractions are also not representable by `int` types. Furthermore, your quadratic probing also fails for `index == 0`, since you will probe 50 times the same index.