# GLSL hashtable data missing:

Tags: c++, hash, glsl, gpu

I already had problems with attempting to hash things before in a previous post: [SSBO hash table, missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280066/ssbo-hash-table-missing-values) I thought the problem was solved but it wasn't completely.

The goal is simple, compress a 3D texture into a linear space using a hashtable.

I am loosing some data, so I am trying to investigate:

[image]

(The black regions int the previous image are missing voxels).

My hash function can create such wholes as anything with more than 10 collisions is discarded, so to investigate whether this was the case I made the following function:

```
int a_size = 100000;
void insert(vec3 pos, Voxel value)
{
    ivec3 discretized = ivec3(pos / v_size);
    int index = int(discretized.x * 73 + discretized.y * 169 + discretized.z * 8349) % a_size;
    index = (a_size + index) % a_size;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if(atomicCompSwap(voxels[index].filled, 0, 1) == 0)
        {
            if(value.position != ivec4(discretized, 1))
            {
                Voxel c_voxel = voxels[index];
                value.position = ivec4(discretized, 1);
                voxels[index] = value;

                if(i==0) {
                    voxels[index].color = vec4(1,0,0,1);
                }
                if(i==1) {
                    voxels[index].color = vec4(0,1,0,1);
                }
                if(i==2) {
                    voxels[index].color = vec4(0,0,1,1);
                }
                if(i==3) {
                    voxels[index].color = vec4(1,0,1,1);
                }
                if(i>=4) {
                    voxels[index].color = vec4(1,0,1,1);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        index = (index * index + 7) % a_size;
    }
}
```

Thus all voxels with no collision are red, those with 1 collisions green...

And if a voxel has 9 collisions or more it becomes white.

In a different shader I proceed to read the values as:

```
int a_size = 100000;
vec4 fetch(vec3 pos)
{
    ivec3 discretized = ivec3(pos / v_size);
    int index = int(discretized.x * 73 + discretized.y * 169 + discretized.z * 8349) % a_size;
    index = (a_size + index) % a_size;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        Voxel c_voxel = voxels[index];

        if(i>=1) {
            return vec4(1);
        }

        if(ivec4(discretized,1) == voxels[index].position)
            return voxels[index].color;

        if(voxels[index].filled == 0) return vec4(0);

        index = (index * index + 7) % a_size;
    }
}
```

Based on the logic of this function, all returned non empty values should be red or white. White voxels denoting more than one collision happened.

The result is:

[image]

As you can see there's a couple of green voxels and no white voxels.

To me, this seems to indicate that my retrieving hash function isn't actually identical to my storing hash function. If they were identical, the expectation is that no green pixels could be visible, as those pixels correspond to voxels with 1 collisions, and those would be overwritten by white. So to return green, the function is returning on the first hash.

The declaration of the voxel and ssbo structures in both shaders is:

```
struct Voxel
{
    int filled;
    int pad1;
    int pad2;
    int pad3;
    ivec4 position;
    vec4 normal;
    vec4 color;
};

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer voxel_buffer
{
    uint index;
    Voxel voxels[];
};
```

Both hashed functions seem identical to me. Changing the a_size parameter also changes the proportion of missing hits, although with no particular number. one million gave the best results, but 900 000 gave better results than  1 100 000

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nztKc.png):